# What library stackoverflow forms use to display error (Bootstrap popover for error help-block)

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a form and I want to display validation error messages. right now I use bootstrap has-error and help-block to show validations. but I really like how error messages are displayed in Stackoverflow's ask Questions Form. Is there a js/css library that is used to show these messages or is this something built by stackoverflow, in either case how can I create something like this in my forms (preferably an extension to bootstrap).

[image]

Comment: Not as you want i think. But it will helps you. Please follow http://jsfiddle.net/B4hYG/9/

Comment: or try this : http://www.girliemac.com/blog/2012/11/21/html5-form-validation/

Answer (score 1):

I got pretty close using bootstrap `poppver`. (Note that I use laravel with bootstrap and jquery). I identify the fields with error from a php variable `$errors`, that gives in input or textarea field names.

[image]

**jquery** to add data- attributes to fields with error

```
{{-- CUSTOM POPOVERS --}}
<script>
jQuery(function(){
    /**
     * Script to highlight erred fields and show popover error messages in form fields
     * This script needs to be in this page, not some js file, as it uses $error php variable
     */
    errors_json = '<?php if (isset($errors)) echo json_encode($errors->toArray()); else echo []; ?>';
    errors = $.parseJSON(errors_json);
    $.each(errors, function (i, val) {
        var input = $('input[name=' + i + ']'+','+'textarea[name=' + i + ']');
        input.attr('title', 'Errors').attr('data-toggle', 'popover').attr('data-trigger', 'focus').attr('data-placement', 'top').attr('data-content', val);
        input.addClass('highlight-error').popover();
    });
});
</script>
```

and **css** to get that red color in bootstrap popovers to indicate errors

```
 .popover {
     background-color: #dd4b39;
     border: 1px solid #b33f2d;
     border: 1px solid rgba(221, 75, 57, 0.25);
     border-radius: 0;
     color: white;
 }
.popover-title {
    background-color: #b33f2d;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    border-radius: 0;
}
.popover-content{

}
.popover.top > .arrow {
    border-top-color: #dd4b39;
    border-top-color: rgba(221, 75, 57, 0.25);
}
.popover.top > .arrow:after {
    border-top-color: #dd4b39;
}
.popover.right > .arrow {
    border-right-color: #dd4b39;
    border-right-color: rgba(221, 75, 57, 0.25);
}
.popover.right > .arrow:after {
    border-right-color: #dd4b39;
}
.popover.bottom > .arrow {
    border-bottom-color: #dd4b39;
    border-bottom-color: rgba(221, 75, 57, 0.25);
}
.popover.bottom > .arrow:after {
    border-bottom-color: #dd4b39;
}
.popover.left > .arrow {
    border-left-color: #dd4b39;
    border-left-color: rgba(221, 75, 57, 0.25);
}
.popover.left > .arrow:after {
    border-left-color: #dd4b39;
}
```